# export-csv only writing on 1st row

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm exporting data from powershell using the export-csv command. everything is working fine (i've stepped thru it with the debbuger and see the data change in the csv file) the only problem is the data is only writing to row 1, over and over.  how can i make it write one line  (i'm using a foreach loop) of data per row?

Comment: Can you please post the code you are using?

Comment: How can anyone guess why your code isn't working if you haven't posted the code? Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and this http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have PS 3.0, you can't use `Export-CSV` to append to a file. Ex:

```
$mylist | Foreach { 
    #Export item til csv.
    $_ | Export-CSV myfile.csv -notypeinformation
}
```

This will overwrite the csv file every time so it always contains a single object, which results in a csv-file containing headers and the LAST object in the loop.

With PowerShell 3.0 you can use the `-Append` switch like this:

```
$mylist | Foreach { 
    #Export item til csv.
    $_ | Export-CSV myfile.csv -notypeinformation -append
}
```

If you don't have PowerShell 3.0, you need manually create csv-output and use something like `out-file -append` in the loop, or export the whole array at the same time(recommended), like:

```
$mylist | Select Name, Age | Export-CSV myfile.csv -notypeinformation
```

I used `Select-object` above to pick out the Properties i wanted in the correct order before exporting to csv.